# Facebook Open Graph Pre-Action Authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Basically, I've just started some development on getting a Facebook Open Graph action for our website. Now I have successfully implemented the Facebook Action and Objects but am getting a bit stuck here as the Facebook documentation doesn't show many advanced examples.

I am trying to have a button on a page that will post an action to a user's wall. However, at the moment the javascript throws an error if the user is not logged in to Facebook or authenticated the Facebook app.

Using the example in Facebook Documentation, this is what I have on my page so far.

My question is how do I adapt this to detect whether a user is logged into Facebook and/or authenticated with my Facebook App?? And if a user is not detected to be logged in/authenticated, display a Login button rather than the share button below.

If a Facebook is logged in, could it then just display the share button as it would do when using the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shareme()
{
FB.api('/me/gradtouch:discover&company=URL','post',
                function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks much appreciate any help, guidance or even if its a direction to where I can read up more about how I could write something that could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few ways to detect whether a user is logged in or not, probably the most useful is to subscribe to the 'auth.statusChange' event

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

This should be called when FB sdk is finished intializing, with the status of the user (whether they are logged into FB, whether they have added your app, whether they are not logged in at all.. see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ )

You can then display the relevant button, and if you need the user to login, just call FB.login() with permissions you need, and your event handler should be called again if their login status changes (ie, if they select to add the app. )

Comment: Thanks alot much appreciate this! Hopefully Ill understand this doc but on quick glance very useful. Cheers!